# split a string of addresses into separate addresses based on country name

Tags: python, string

I have This String

```
text = "11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 9046 Sorenson Avenue, Sante Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 8771 Sorenson Avenue, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 42685 Rio Nedo, Temecula, CA 92590 United States Steven Label De Mexico Facility Calle Ferrocarril #17030 Fraccionamiento Ninos, Heroes Este Parque Industrial Limon, Los Pinos, Baja California 22123 Mexico 755 West Big Beaver Road, Suite 1340 Troy, Michigan 48084"
```

These are some addresses (my sample is not limited to these two countries) I want to put separately to get an output like this:

```
['11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States',
 '11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States',
 '11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States',
 '9046 Sorenson Avenue, Sante Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States',
 '8771 Sorenson Avenue, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States',
 '42685 Rio Nedo, Temecula, CA 92590 United States',
 'Steven Label De Mexico Facility Calle Ferrocarril #17030 Fraccionamiento Ninos, Heroes Este Parque Industrial Limon, Los Pinos, Baja California 22123 Mexico',
 'Este Parque Industrial Limon, Los Pinos, Baja California 22123 Mexico',
 '55 West Big Beaver Road, Suite 1340 Troy, Michigan 48084']
```

I thought about splitting based on country name so I tried this:

```
import pycountry
for country in pycountry.countries:
    if country.name in text:
        print(text.split(country.name))
```

But got this:

```
['11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 9046 Sorenson Avenue, Sante Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 8771 Sorenson Avenue, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 United States 42685 Rio Nedo, Temecula, CA 92590 United States Steven Label De ', ' Facility Calle Ferrocarril #17030 Fraccionamiento Ninos, Heroes Este Parque Industrial Limon, Los Pinos, Baja California 22123 ', ' 755 West Big Beaver Road, Suite 1340 Troy, Michigan 48084']
['11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 ', ' 11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 ', ' 11926 Burke Street, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 ', ' 9046 Sorenson Avenue, Sante Fe Springs, CA 90670 ', ' 8771 Sorenson Avenue, Santa Fe Springs, CA 90670 ', ' 42685 Rio Nedo, Temecula, CA 92590 ', ' Steven Label De Mexico Facility Calle Ferrocarril #17030 Fraccionamiento Ninos, Heroes Este Parque Industrial Limon, Los Pinos, Baja California 22123 Mexico 755 West Big Beaver Road, Suite 1340 Troy, Michigan 48084']
```

So How can I split the string based on Country Name?

Comment: split() return the list of splitted element WITHOUT the separator, so you will have an issue here and some of your addresses seem to have the country name in the street field so it will split in the middle of the street field (e.g. "Steven Label De Mexico Facility Calle" there is Mexico which seems to be in your country list). Maybe use re.split instead and search pattern with numbers before your countries to be sure you are looking for the right thing.

Comment: Your last address has a different form than the others in that it does not include the country i.e. **755 West Big Beaver Road, Suite 1340 Troy, Michigan 48084**.

Comment: The Mexico example inexplicably splits into two places i.e. **Steven Label De Mexico Facility Calle Ferrocarril #17030 Fraccionamiento Ninos, Heroes Este Parque Industrial Limon, Los Pinos, Baja California 22123 Mexico** is two places in Mexico: 1) 'Steven Label De Mexico Facility Calle Ferrocarril #17030 Fraccionamiento Ninos, Heroes Este Parque Industrial Limon, Los Pinos, Baja California 22123 Mexico', and 2) 'Este Parque Industrial Limon, Los Pinos, Baja California 22123 Mexico'.

Comment: Right, But any ideas?

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud--I have an idea that works for the US entries but Mexico is tough for the reason I cited above. Would this be helpful?

Comment: unfortunately No, but thank you